# "method _default of object range failed" in Worksheet_Change code

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

When I change a value in the column specified (column 19), the code takes a while to run but seems to work properly, then throws the error. This also causes Excel to crash repeatedly as I'm trying to debug the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 19 Then
        If Target <> "yes" Then
            Target = "no"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried changing Target to activecell, using explicit references, etc and everything seems to throw the same error and crash Excel.

Any Ideas?

Comment: `Target = "no"` causes the event to fire in an infinite loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure

Comment: `Target <> "yes"` will fail if `Target` corresponds to a multi-cell range.

Comment: @BigBen changing to `If Target <> "yes" And Target <> "no" Then` did the trick! Your other comment is another issue I didn't think of, but it would take more work to fix it than its worth, so I'll just keep that in mind. Thanks! That makes sense, the `Worksheeet_Change` method is firing itself by changing the worksheet.
Edit: the link you provided makes it quite easy actually, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change every not "yes" element to "no"?

```
Sub stringToNo()
    columnNumber = 19
    lastrow = fLastRow

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, columnNumber) <> "yes" Then
            Cells(i, columnNumber) = "no"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Function fLastRow() As Long
    fLastRow = 0
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
        fLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm mainly using this so that if I want to remove a "yes", I can just press delete on the cell and it will change it back to a "no", or I suppose If someone tries to enter an obscure value in the column it just stays "no"